# Is it possible to set file permission according to the user privilege? If yes how?

Tags: linux, file, linux-kernel

I want to set a file permission according to user privilege level (like Administrator, Operator, User, etc.,). I want to assign root permissions to user's that who have administrator privilege. If possible how to set. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

"Like Administrator, Operator, User, etc" are all examples of *roles*.  In Linux (as in Windows), a common way implement roles is is to use *groups*.

Create (or use an existing) group, set ownership and permissions on the resource, and assign users to the group.

You might also be interested in [Role Based Access Control](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/selg-overview.html) (RBAC) provided by SELinux.  SELinux is a feature available for most Linux distros:

- http://www.ukfast.co.uk/blog/2010/08/16/role-based-access-controls-in-enterprise-linux-6/
- http://selinuxproject.org/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-rbac-selinux/